# Lyx citation problem

Tags: lyx, citing

I'm trying to get citations working with LyX but I've found that I'm getting the entire citation listed. So where it should say [1] I am getting `Example(John Tosh…)` ect. My document preamble is:

```
\usepackage{nag}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[style=oscola,
natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{/Users/jamie/Documents/Law and History}
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage[natbib=true,
style=numeric,
style=oscola]{biblatex}
\bibliography{/Users/jamie/Documents/Law and History}


\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG\citet{Tosh:2010aa} dfdasfads
\citep{Tosh:2010aa}



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With that document I am getting: `THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG\footciteref Tosh dfdasfads (ibid)' instead of`the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. [1]

Comment: Please **complete** your code to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is a lot easier to help when you include all the necessary code to reproduce the issue and eliminate unnecessary packages which are unrelated to the problem. Who knows? You may even solve the problem yourself in the process of creating your MWE!

Comment: I think the problem lies with \usepackage[style=oscola,
natbib=true]{biblatex} .I also have the biblatex.module enabled. Thank you for your time

Comment: So use a different style or don't use `natbib`. Really, if you don't provide code so somebody can reproduce the issue but only say you think you already know what the problem is, I'm not sure quite what you think somebody can say.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't be more helpful, I am quite new to lyx and latex. I think I am doing something wrong with the way I have set up that line and I can't work out what. If I remove style=oscola, then I get the proper [1] format. Sadly I have to use OSCOLA, because it is a required standard.

Comment: Did you read the information in the link I provided? Producing an MWE is not difficult - tedious, sometimes, but it does not require any particular skills, LaTeX or otherwise. Moreover, I'm confused. The point of loading the style is to comply with it. If you need to use that style, you need that style. The fact that it gives different output is *expected*. That is the job of a style - it changes the formatting of references and/or citations. (Both in this case.) So if you are meant to use it, you are meant to use it. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: By the way, I don't get what you say you get. With that style, the citations are given in footnotes marked by superscripts.

Comment: I have edited in a MWE. Oscola citations are supposed to go `example[1]' with the citation in a footnote. I seem to get `example(John Tosh…)- which is the text that is supposed to be in the footnotes. Also my test .bib file contains:@book{Tosh:2010aa,
 Author = {John Tosh},
 Date-Added = {2014-04-16 19:55:53 +0000},
 Date-Modified = {2014-04-16 21:08:10 +0000},
 Edition = {5},
 Publisher = {Pearson},
 Read = {0},
 Title = {The Persuit of History},
 Year = {2010}}

Comment: I'm not sure that `oscala` supports `\citet`. Do you have regular footnotes as well? If so, do they need to be formatted the same way? If you load `style=numeric` it overwrites all of the config `style=oscala` does so that's definitely not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial, possible solution. I'm not sure if this will work for you or not because it depends a great deal on what else is going on in your document. This reformats footnote markers so that they conform to the requirements of the citation style.

I've used a sample bib entry from the example file provided by the package and some of the code you originally posted. I've also noted a couple of other things I think you could improve easily in terms of options you are using.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% much better than OT1
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% much better to switch to utf8 if you can
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oscola,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@legislation{gorchymyn,
    title          = {Gorchymyn Mesur Teithio gan Ddysgwyr (Cymru) (Cychwyn Rhif 2)\nopunct},
    number         = {SI 2009\slash 2819},
    pagination     = {regulation},
    keywords       = {cy},
    userb          = {Cy 245},
    entrysubtype   = {secondary},
    language       = {welsh},
}% entry from oscola documentation
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\let\citet\footcite% horrible kludge

\makeatletter
  \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}% this redefines the way footnote markers are formatted. It will affect *all* footnotes - not just citations.
\makeatother

\begin{document}

THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG\citet{gorchymyn} dfdasfads

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: A citation and reference]

`\citet` does not seem to work without a kludge (above) but `\citep` does.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the kludge to citep and it works perfectly in Lyx. I think the problem stems from Lyx's problems with Biblatex and some issues with Natbib. Without your help, I would never of got it to work.

Comment: @Jim No problem. Glad it helped. I think the main problem actually had nothing to do with citations as such but just to do with the formatting of footnotes. But figuring this out was complicated by the problems with `\citet` - I'm not sure if this is an incompatibility (`natbib` + `oscola`) or a more general issue but it certainly caused some weird and not-very-transparent errors! Note that you are not actually using `natbib` this way. Rather, `biblatex` just maps standard `natbib` commands to rough `biblatex` equivalents. (But not, it seems, `\citet`...)